# Finding the position of super nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find the exact position and access all properties of the super nested array of objects.

I'm struggling to create a function where if I give index number as input parameter it should give me it's position in the array and also access all the properties in return.

Here is the sample array of object

**I'm OK with ES6 and above solution too**

```js
{
 "name": "branch 1",
 "index": 1,
 "children": [{
   "name": "sub child 1",
   "index": 2,
   "children": [{
    "name": "subx2 child 1",
    "index": 3,
    "children": [{
      "name": "subx3 child 1",
      "index": 4,
      "children": [{
        "name": "subx4 child 1",
        "index": 21
       },
       {
        "name": "subx4 child 2",
        "index": 18
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "name": "subx3 child 2",
      "index": 6,
      "children": [{
        "name": "subx4 child 1",
        "index": 7
       },
       {
        "name": "subx4 child 2",
        "index": 21
       }
      ]

     },
     {
      "name": "subx3 child 3",
      "index": 22
     }
    ]
   }]
  },
  {
   "name": "sub child 2",
   "index": 28
  }
 ]
}
```

Yeah I know this json object is scary enough to spend time and solve. Any kind of help is greatly appriciated.

for example if my function name is *findChildIndex(22)* it should return me something like this *x.children[0].children[0].children[2]*

Thank you!

Comment: *"it should give me it's position in the array and also access all the properties in return"*: please provide a concrete example of input and expected output.

Comment: For example, my function name is findChildIndex(indexNumber) for example if 22 it should return me it's the position return me this children[0].children[0].children[2]

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself why this data is structured like this. Flat data is better for json.

Comment: @JoeLloyd This data is used for https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree so can't help! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could recursively collect the indexes in the `children` arrays that lead to the target index:

```js
function findIndexNested(data, index) {
    if (data.index === index) return [];
    let result;
    const i = (data.children || []).findIndex(child => {
        return result = findIndexNested(child, index)
    });
    if (result) return [i, ...result];
}
function findByPath(data, path) {
    for (let i of path) data = data.children[i];
    return data
}
// Sample data
const data = {"name": "branch 1","index": 1,"children": [{"name": "sub child 1","index": 2,"children": [{"name": "subx2 child 1","index": 3,"children": [{"name": "subx3 child 1","index": 4,"children": [{"name": "subx4 child 1","index": 21},{"name": "subx4 child 2","index": 18}]},{"name": "subx3 child 2","index": 6,"children": [{"name": "subx4 child 1","index": 7},{"name": "subx4 child 2","index": 21}]},{"name": "subx3 child 3","index": 22}]}]},{"name": "sub child 2","index": 28}]}
const index = 22
const result = findIndexNested(data, index);
console.log("Found index " + index + " via these child indexes: " + result);
console.log("The object is", findByPath(data, result));
```

Comment: Thanks, @trincot for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: how can I form `Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]` from the array return [0,0,2] ?

Comment: You mean, as a string?

Comment: yes like I want to store it in variable as `var properties = Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]`. If you can please help me

Comment: Wait, that is not a string. You mean `var properties = "Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]"`?

Comment: sorry I don't mean string  i want like this `var properties = Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]` can you please help?

Comment: sorry I don't mean string i want like this `var properties = Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]` can you please help?

Comment: But that is a plain reference to the child object. You would just have `properties` pointing the the deepest object without trace how to get there. If `Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]` is not a string, then you don't have the path, just the object reference.

Comment: Maybe you mean to have a function that will return that child object when you pass it an array like [0, 0, 2]?

Comment: Yes @trincot sir, that's exactly what I'm looking for! :) Is that possible?

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion and check if `children` of the element exists use `for` loop to iterate to through all the `children` and recursively apply the function of each child

```js
const obj = {
 "name": "branch 1",
 "index": 1,
 "children": [{
   "name": "sub child 1",
   "index": 2,
   "children": [{
    "name": "subx2 child 1",
    "index": 3,
    "children": [{
      "name": "subx3 child 1",
      "index": 4,
      "children": [{
        "name": "subx4 child 1",
        "index": 21
       },
       {
        "name": "subx4 child 2",
        "index": 18
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "name": "subx3 child 2",
      "index": 6,
      "children": [{
        "name": "subx4 child 1",
        "index": 7
       },
       {
        "name": "subx4 child 2",
        "index": 21
       }
      ]

     },
     {
      "name": "subx3 child 3",
      "index": 22
     }
    ]
   }]
  },
  {
   "name": "sub child 2",
   "index": 28
  }
 ]
}

function find(obj,index){
  if(obj.children){
    for(let i = 0;i<obj.children.length;i++){
      let x = find(obj.children[i],index);
      if(x) return {...x,pos:i};
    }

  }
  return obj.index === index ? obj : false;
}

console.log(find(obj,21))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Just one question here 

How can I know the index position where it is present like for 22 it could be Obj.children[0].children[0].children[2]

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question correctly, You can do something like this:

```
const func=(obj,index, nested=0)=>{
    return Obj.index===index ? {obj, nested} : func(obj.children,index, nested+1)
}
```